# Why is inline-declared itab not initialized in AT SELECTION SCREEN OUTPUT?

Tags: abap

I have the following piece of code.

```
REPORT YYY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t_test,
    test TYPE c LENGTH 4,
  END OF t_test,
  tth_test TYPE HASHED TABLE OF t_test WITH UNIQUE KEY test.

DATA(g_tab_test) = VALUE tth_test( ( test = 'AAAA' ) ( test = 'BBBB' )
  ( test = 'CCCC' ) ( test = 'DDDD' ) ).

PARAMETERS:
  p_x1 TYPE abap_bool,
  p_x2 TYPE abap_bool,
  p_x3 TYPE abap_bool.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT screen.
    MODIFY SCREEN.
  ENDLOOP.
  BREAK-POINT. "<-- why is the table g_tab_test not initialsed here yet?

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_x1.
  ASSERT 1 = 1.
```

Despite its definition, the table at the point of break in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT` is empty. Why is it so and is it a documented behaviour?

Comment: It is astonishing to see such questions from such experienced member :)

Comment: Not really, no. :) Those inline declarations aren't that old you know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is a documented behaviour.

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapstart-of-selection.htm

> In an executable program, the following statements are assigned to an
>   implicit START-OF-SELECTION event block, which is inserted by an
>   explicit START-OF-SELECTION event block if one exists:
>
> All statements that are not declaration and are listed before the
>   first explicit processing block.
>
> All functional statements in the program if it does not contain any
>   explicit processing blocks,

The code is "in the air", not explicitly under an exact event, this means the initialization of the internal table will run only with the implicit `START-OF-SELECTION`.

The code piece needs to be under `INITIALIZATION` (or `LOAD-OF-PROGRAM` depending on the exact need)